# Is the ArcMap style database format available somewhere?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, cartography, symbology, style

The *.style files are MS Access databases where each style type is a table.
The table has one binary column where the actual style is written. 
Is this binary format available?
I would like to import some custom color ramps, but I can't see a way to do it... and I hoped in the style database!

Comment: Can you point us to some online examples we could download and look at? I'm curious...

Comment: Have found some now, but having trouble extracting the OLE type in the Color Ramps table (am using Linux...).

Comment: Here is a stripped down style DB. It only contains some color ramps http://giovanniallegri.it/share/GIOHAPPY.style

Answer (score 1):

I think these **[Tips for editing your style files with Microsoft Access](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2007/10/30/tips-for-managing-style-files/)** may be your best lead in or **[Ask A Cartographer](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.gateway)**.